# Match & Transpose data in Python

Tags: python-3.x

New to Python and trying to see how I might be able to incorporate it at work.

I have two data sets. One contains a list of Chapters and Committee Members.  The second data set contains a list of chapters and their president.

Data Set 1 (2 columns)

Chapter   Committee Member
NY        Jerry Seinfeld
NY        Robert Dinero
NY        Cynthia Nixon
FL        Mickey Mouse
FL        Donald Duck

Data Set 2 (2 columns)

Chapter    President
NY         Alicia Keys
FL         Gloria Estefan

I would like to get the following, with each name in its own columns (number of columns would vary by # of committee members):

Chapter  President       Com_Member1      Com_Member2    Com_Member 3...
NY       Alicia Keys     Jerry Seinfeld   Robert Dinero  Cynthia Nixon
FL       Gloria Estefan  Mickey Mouse     Donald Duck

Can someone advise me on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard from your question what your data set is, I will assume that it is two dictionaries. Please tell me if this is wrong.

```
commite = {"NY":["jerry","mickey","etc"],"FL":["goofey","donald"]}
presidents = {"NY":"Alicia Keys","FL":"Gloria Estefan"}

final = {key:[pres]+commite[key]  for key,pres in presidents.items()}
>>> {'NY': ['Alicia Keys', 'jerry', 'mickey', 'etc'], 'FL': ['Gloria Estefan', 'goofey', 'donald']}
```

The way it works is it uses dictionary comprehension, it takes each president and key(state). It uses the key as the key, and the value is the president along with the commite. If you want the presidents as a list just change final to this.

```
final = {key:pres+commite[key]  for key,pres in presidents.items()}
```

Comment: It's actually two csv files at the moment.  I was unsure about the best way to bring it in but I'll start with creating the dictionaries and trying the code you provided.